# SQL query for calling multiple columns with conditions

Tags: sql

I want to write an SQL query calling for several columns with conditions.
The table looks like this.

```
organisation          A           B          C           D
Ikea         2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea         2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29  2018-07-01   
Orange       2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea         2018-06-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
Nestle       2018-06-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
Ikea         2018-05-04  2018-05-05  2018-04-02  2018-06-01
```

And I want to get a row where the organisation is Ikea, and where the earliest date among four columns (A, B, C, D) is between 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-31. Therefore only the second the fourth row of the original table above match the conditions.

So the result I want to get should be:

```
organisation          A           B          C           D
Ikea         2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29  2018-07-01    
Ikea         2018-06-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26
```

How should I write an SQL query? 
Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea 
AND (A >= "2018-05-01" AND A <= "2018-05-31") 
OR (B >= "2018-05-01" AND B <= "2018-05-31") 
OR (C >= "2018-05-01" AND C <= "2018-05-31") 
OR (D >= "2018-05-01" AND D <= "2018-05-31")
```

EDIT::
Now I realised that I need to deal with NA values, where if a row contains NAs, I want to ignore the NAs and see the earliest date among the rest of the values. I created [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043189/sql-query-for-calling-multiple-columns-with-conditionswith-nas) for this, so please take a look. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: `AND` is usually higher priority than `OR`, so what You probably need is `... Ikea AND (... OR ... OR ... OR ...)`. Otherwise it is treated as `(... Ikea AND ...) OR ... OR ... OR ...`.

Comment: i think your result will be 1 and 4th row

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I'm using MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the earliest date among four columns (A, B, C, D) is between 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-31.

Most databases support the `least()` function, so you would appear to want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
WHERE t.organisation LIKE 'Ikea' AND
      LEAST(a, b, c, d) >= '2018-05-01' AND
      LEAST(a, b, c, d) < '2018-06-01';
```

You can construct similar logic in a database that doesn't support `LEAST()`, but this gives the ides.

Notes:

- The second argument to `LIKE` should be a string.
- The standard delimiter in SQL for string and date constants is the single quote, not the double quote.
- I don't recommend using `BETWEEN` on date/time columns.  If the dates have a time component, then it will not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This looks like a great solution but unfortunately it doesn't return the desired table. I 'm using MySQL server and I'm actually working on R Studio.

Comment: Ok now I got why it doesn't work. I need to consider that there is NA in the table. I will ask another question regarding this. But for now your answer seems to be the closest to my desired output! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if I got it right but I think the operator between the dates columns must be AND instead of OR. Also you could use the BETWEEN operator in order to check if the dates are included in the time span:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea 
AND A BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31" 
AND B BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31" 
AND C BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31" 
AND D BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31"
```

or as @Roman suggested in the comments you should group the OR conditions as

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea 
AND (
    A BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31" 
 OR B BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31" 
 OR C BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31" 
 OR D BETWEEN "2018-05-01" AND "2018-05-31"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

by using Mysql Query would be below like this

```
 select * from myTable
    where organisation='Ikea'
and LEAST(A,B,C,D)>= date('2018-05-01') 
and LEAST(A,B,C,D) < date('2018-06-01')
```