# SQL query for calling multiple columns with conditions(with NAs)

Tags: mysql, sql, r, conditional-statements, rmysql

This is a continuous question from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039663/sql-query-for-calling-multiple-columns-with-conditions?noredirect=1#comment89070952_51039663). I want to write an SQL query calling for several columns with conditions. I'm working on R Studio using RMySQL package. My server is MySQL.

The table looks like this.

```
organisation          A           B           C           D
Ikea         2018-04-01  2018-05-07  2018-05-09  2018-05-01
Ikea         2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA   
Orange       2018-04-02  2018-05-01  2018-07-08  2018-05-26 
Ikea         2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Nestle       2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
Ikea                 NA  2018-05-05  2018-04-02  2018-06-01
```

And I want to get a row where the organisation is Ikea, and where the earliest date among four columns (A, B, C, D) is between 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-31.

In a row which contains NA values, I want to ignore the NAs and see what's the earliest date among the rest of the values. For example, for the second row, the earliest date is "2018-05-03"(column B) therefore it meets the criteria.

Therefore only the second the fourth row of the original table above match the conditions. And the result I want to get should be:

```
organisation          A           B           C           D
Ikea         2018-06-01  2018-05-03  2018-05-29          NA    
Ikea         2018-06-02  2018-05-01          NA  2018-05-26
```

How should I write an SQL query? 
Here is my attempt after getting an answer from my previous question, but it doesn't work well for rows with NAs.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea
LEAST(A, B, C, D) >= '2018-05-01' AND
LEAST(A, B, C, D) < '2018-06-01'
```

Thank you for any kinds of help!

Comment: Often, I have advised data analysts to keep data long in R, Pandas, etc. but this is an absolute must in database tables for efficiency, scalability, storage. Normalized structured are easier to query. If possible, reshape the table with **one** date value column, **one** letter indicator column, and **one** *organisation* column. Then aggregation is simple with min and max.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Due to the hierarchy in my company it was a bit difficult to reshape the table i a desired way you mentioned. But indeed it would be the best solution if I could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE 'Ikea' AND
      LEAST(COALESCE(A, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(B, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(C, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(D, '2019-01-01')) >= '2018-05-01' AND
      LEAST(COALESCE(A, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(B, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(C, '2019-01-01'), COALESCE(D, '2019-01-01')) < '2018-06-01';
```

`'2019-01-01'` is an arbitrary date *after* the range.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `IFNULL()` for the values and use `getdate()` so if it were null it would just use today and then that wouldnt be considered the least which is basically ignoring them.

like: `LEAST(IFNULL(A,getdate()), IFNULL(B,getdate()), IFNULL(C,getdate()), IFNULL(D,getdate()))`

hopefully this may push you in the correct direction

unless `NA` is a string in there which you could use a case statement like `case when A = 'NA' THEN getdate() end`

could end up looking something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea
LEAST(IFNULL(A,getdate()), IFNULL(B,getdate()), IFNULL(C,getdate()), IFNULL(D,getdate())) >= '2018-05-01' AND
LEAST(IFNULL(A,getdate()), IFNULL(B,getdate()), IFNULL(C,getdate()), IFNULL(D,getdate())) < '2018-06-01'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE organisation LIKE Ikea
LEAST(case when A = 'NA' THEN getdate() else A end, case when B = 'NA' THEN getdate() else B end, case when C = 'NA' THEN getdate() else C end, case when D = 'NA' THEN getdate() else D end) >= '2018-05-01' AND
LEAST(case when A = 'NA' THEN getdate() else A end, case when B = 'NA' THEN getdate() else B end, case when C = 'NA' THEN getdate() else C end, case when D = 'NA' THEN getdate() else D end) < '2018-06-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider joining on an aggregate query derived using a `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT t.ID, MIN(t.`DateValue`) As MinDate
    FROM 
       (SELECT ID, organisation, 'A' As 'Category', A As `DateValue` FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, organisation, 'B' As 'Category', B As `DateValue` FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, organisation, 'C' As 'Category', C As `DateValue` FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, organisation, 'D' As 'Category', D As `DateValue` FROM myTable) As t
    WHERE t.organisation = 'Ikea'
    GROUP BY t.ID
    HAVING MIN(t.`DateValue`) >= '2018-05-01' AND MIN(t.`DateValue`) < '2018-06-01') As agg
ON m.ID = agg.ID;
```

[RexTester Demo](http://rextester.com/GEZX29916) *(Note: dates are in DD-MM-YYYY format)*

[image: SQL Query Results]